# writing "Comparator" in SQL

Tags: sql, comparator

I have the following problem:

find the highest row in a table A according to the following rules:

Table A
Columns: V_Date Date, Type int, H_Date Date

1) find the highest V_Date
2) if V_Dates are the same find the row with the highest Priority, where Priority is defined in Table B with columns Type int, Priority int
3) if V_Date and Priority are the same, find the one with the highest H_Date (then it is guaranteed to be unique)

The priorities are not distinct, so max (prio) returns more than one value.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use ORDER BY and limit the result to one row:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON TableA.Type = TableB.Type
ORDER BY V_Date DESC, Priority DESC, H_DATE DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Exact syntax may vary depending on the specific database.

- In MySQL and PostgreSQL you can use `LIMIT 1` as above.
- In SQL Server you can use `SELECT TOP(1)`.
- In Oracle you can use `SELECT * FROM (subquery here) WHERE rownum = 1`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help, seems I ran in complete wrong direction... (selecting max())

Comment: You helped me, but now I'm stuck again. I need not only the last of all rows, but the last the n for all rows of table C, which has a 1 to n relation to table A.
I hope that was clear. 
Table C has a 1 to n relation to A and for each row in C I need the last row of A. Can I express this in SQL? Or do I need a stored procedure / for loop? I have the restriction to express it in SQL by the way.

Comment: @Thirdman: I would run the above in a subquery and then join in TableC in an outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework (if it isn't, tell me). So you'll get a general answer. More detail might require you to specify the db type.

`JOIN` the tables. Use the `ORDER BY` statement in combination with the `TOP` statement.

Comment: That's not home work. sorry if this is too easy. I'm a Java Expert, not a SQL Expert.

Comment: No need to say sorry - it was a wrong assumption on my end. In that case, Mark's answer should be good to use.